# Mysql store data in array then sort desc

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following array and I would like to populate it with 2 columns from mysql. I have tried and I can't seem to work it out. Any help will be appreciated

mysql table is the following:

IDNO | NAME

```
 <?php
$age = array(

$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_suburbs LIMIT 10");

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{       
$row2['name']=>$row2['id']
}

 "Ben"=>"37",
 "Joe"=>"43",
 );
arsort($age);

foreach($age as $x => $x_value)
 {
 echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
 echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: where is your mysql query?

Comment: You are not even trying to populate the array with things coming from a resultset in your answer.

Comment: There are a lot of errors in this script, it won't even get through the parser... **$row2['name']=>$row2['id']** is wrong, there seems to be an array declaration, but its missing a couple lines... The title of your question talks about sorting, but not your post, what's up with that? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: the issue i have is when i use the code without mysql it works find when i try implement mysql it stops working my question should be how can i implement the 2

Comment: This avoids having to sort in php: `SELECT name, age FROM tbl ORDER BY age DESC`

Comment: that would be ok if i didnt need to sort another value from another DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is not 100% clear. And code is wrong.

Let me try to guess what do you really looking for:

```
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_suburbs ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 10");

$age = array();

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{       
  $age[$row2['name']]=$row2['age']; 
}

foreach($age as $x => $x_value)
 {
 echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
 echo "<br>";
}
```

Let ne know if you need some clarification and/or improvements.